# Emulator process terminated

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to run Android emulator from device manager. Got error:

```
Device Manager
The emulator process for AVD Pixel_2_API_34 has terminated.
```

What might be reason of this error? How to fix it?

[image]

Content of idea.log:

```
2023-07-13 15:06:18,130 [  11329]   INFO - #c.g.s.f.i.c.FirebaseAppManager - New app states on sync SKIPPED: {Module: 'empty_activity.app'=FirebaseApp(module=Module: 'empty_activity.app', connections=[])}.
2023-07-13 15:06:18,278 [  11477]   INFO - #c.a.t.n.s.NativeWorkspaceModificationTask - NDK support for project 'empty_activity' is disabled because the project doesn't contain any valid native configurations.
2023-07-13 15:06:18,402 [  11601]   INFO - #o.j.p.g.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/jbr
2023-07-13 15:06:22,691 [  15890]   INFO - #o.j.j.b.i.CompilerReferenceIndex - backward reference index version doesn't exist
2023-07-13 15:06:22,696 [  15895]   INFO - #c.i.c.b.IsUpToDateCheckStartupActivity - suitable consumer is not found
2023-07-13 15:06:22,707 [  15906]   WARN - #c.a.t.i.d.WindowsPerformanceHintsChecker - Error retrieving list of excluded patterns: Error code 5: Access is denied.
2023-07-13 15:06:22,710 [  15909]   INFO - #c.a.t.i.d.WindowsPerformanceHintsChecker - Windows Defender status: UNKNOWN_STATUS; projectDirExcluded? false
2023-07-13 15:06:22,822 [  16021]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.DelayedProjectSynchronizer - Workspace model loaded from cache. Syncing real project state into workspace model in 118 ms. Thread[ApplicationImpl pooled thread 9,4,main]
2023-07-13 15:06:58,403 [  51602]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel XL API 34 - C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_XL_API_34 -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300
2023-07-13 15:06:58,427 [  51626]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel XL API 34 - Android emulator version 32.1.14.0 (build_id 10330179) (CL:N/A)
2023-07-13 15:06:58,427 [  51626]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel XL API 34 - Found systemPath C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-34\google_apis\x86_64\
2023-07-13 15:06:58,527 [  51726]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel XL API 34 - Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\g\.android\avd\Pixel_XL_API_34.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
2023-07-13 15:07:01,553 [  54752]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel XL API 34 - Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374)
2023-07-13 15:07:01,555 [  54754] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel XL API 34 - Emulator terminated with exit code -1073740940
java.lang.Throwable: Emulator terminated with exit code -1073740940
```